# Edit system files from within Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, network-programming, operating-system

I am putting together a web interface for an embedded hardware product (think like your router) that needs the ability to change system files that are owned by root. In particular I need to change the network address and then restart the service.

What is the best way to handle this both for editing the file and securely handling the escalation (preferably outside of the webapp somehow). I had the idea of a user who can sudo with no password for scripts to use that was banned from SSH or Terminal login, but I am unsure if this is the best thing to do security wise as it leaves that user open to attacks that can then escalate privleges.

I effectively want to read ifcfg-eth0, write changes to a temporary file, double check those changes are valid, then write it back to the ifcfg-eth0 original file, finally restart the network interface.